# constructor error

Tags: java

I was told that when creating a new object, it needs to have the same parameters as its constructor. Ive tried, but i still get these error. cannot find symbol s1.getCourse s1.getName s1.getAge. and also an invalid constructor error. heres my code

```
    public class Person{ 
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Person(String name, int age){
    this.name=name;
    this.age=age;
    }
    public String getDetails(){
    return "Name: " + name + "Age: " + age;
    }

    public void setName(String name){
    this.name=name;
    }
    public void setAge(int age){
    this.age=age;
    }

public String getName(){
return name;
}
public int getAge(){
return age;
}
        public class Student extends Person{
           private String course;

           public Student(String name, int age,String course){
               super(name,age);
               this.course = course;
           }
           public String getDetails(){
               return super.getDetails()+"Course: "+ course;
           }
           public void setCourse(String course){
               this.course=course;
           }
           public String getCourse(){
               return course;
           }

           public String getName(){
               return name;
           }
        }

       public String getAge(){
          return age;
       }
    }
```

TestPerson

```
    student++;
    String name=array[0];
    int age=Integer.parseInt(array[1]);
    String course=array[3];
    Student s1= new Student(name,age,course);


    System.out.println("name "+s1.getName());
    System.out.println("age "+ s1.getAge());
    System.out.println("course: " + s1.getCourse());

    }
 }
```

Comment: Please show us the error message.  Also are you importing the `Student` class?

Comment: Anre `name` and `age` protected or public?

Comment: `cannot find symbol s1.getCourse s1.getName s1.getAge` are these the first errors you get? Did you add those methods after creating `TestPerson` and if so, did you recompile `Student`?

Comment: If this is homework, you should tag with a `homework` tag. Also, when you say `String course=array[3]`, were you expecting to get a String that was 3 characters long, or 3 strings? Your creator `new Student(name,age,course);` is expecting neither; it expects a single string.

Comment: I don't understand how this would even compile when the data type for `age` doesn't match. In one place you're specifying it as an `int` and in another you're specifying it as a `String`.

Comment: Why `getAge()` is outside of Student class? What does 2 closing braces in `TestPerson` mean. Also at one place `age` is `int` as argument and in `getAge` method you are returning it as `String` without even converting it to String. Please show proper code. Its very confusing.

Comment: You shouldn't need to define getName and getAge, these should be inherited. getDetails should have another space at the start of the string otherwise it might not be readable.

Comment: You really need to go back to the basics. I highly recommend that you read [Learning the Java Language](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html) tutorial.

Comment: oops. sorry, typo. i meant public int getAge. sorry. ill post the person class

Answer (score 0):

For more Detail can u provide Person class.

You have not provided the name and age attribute in student class.
if all this is present in super class then also When u call the s1.getName() method it will call from student class. because it present in sub class i.e student

Comment: can some one help? it says cannot find symbol s1.getName() but they are inherited through the person class.